# Use HttpListener to get WebBrowser control Requests/Responses?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control, httplistener

Is it possible to use HttpListener to get the requests responses sent by webbrowser control? I'm trying to figure out the URL's the server send back (200 & 204).

I have been looking for many solution like webbrowser wrapper but I need something simple to view webbrowser control URL of the requests/responses and use them as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view your requests and responses  by using Fiddler:

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: I need to use it in my program